# Javascript + PHP set countodwn with form

Tags: javascript, php, html, timer

I have set_timer.php file with a form in which the admin user can set the date and time of match ending. It all works fine if I stay on the page timer.php, but when i want to include timer.php on my webpage footer it retuns Nan.

set_timer.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Natavi timer</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<form action="timer.php" method="post">
End of the match: <input type="text" name="date" value="03/15/2015 6:30 PM"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Start">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

timer.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$date=$_POST['date'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Timer</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script>
CountDownTimer('<?php echo $date; ?>', 'countdown');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
        var end = new Date(dt);

        var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        function showRemaining() {
            var now = new Date();
            var distance = end - now;
            if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'Konec tekme!';

                return;
            }
            var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ' days ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + ' hours ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + ' minutes ';
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + ' seconds';
        }

        timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="countdown"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then i just include my timer.php in the webpage footer.

```
<div id="footer"><?php include 'timer.php'; ?></div>
```

Comment: You can't use `session_start()` after you've sent output (html) to the browser - which you're doing before the include. Try putting `session_start()` at the top of your main site code.

Comment: I am using `session_start()` on the top of my page but it seems like something is resetting the variable.

Comment: Include Statement should not be used that way, if you look at what you are trying to do , you are duplicating html tags HTML, BODY, ETC

I strongly suggest you to develop a new structure where only php goes in one side, your html goes in another and if you could do that also with your js, it would be great. By Now just looking over it my guess is not even your html is working properly,

regards

Comment: @Bulk totally right, regards

Comment: @DiegoCoderPlus but how can I get the textbox value to javascript if u use separated files?

Comment: @cufare several ways, one is to include in the beggining your php file , and then you will just add the minimum php needed inside the div, for example a php variable containing all you need from the server side, another easy way is to make an ajax call to the php and the response then will affect that div using jquery .

Comment: @DiegoCoderPlus so i have to make a separated timer.js with the javascript and include that on the page, that works for me if i set the value for the date like this: `CountDownTimer('03/18/2015 6:30 PM', 'countdown');`, but how can i set the date value with a form?

Comment: Store/assign the POST array to a session variable. *Done like dinner*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- and include it in js like before, just with the session variable?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code again, I think this is your error:

```
session_start();
$date=$_POST['date'];
```

Should be

```
session_start();
$date=$_SESSION['date'];
```

To make proper use of the session variables.

Answer (score 0):

The $date comes from a $_POST not from session, so, when you include timer.php with you don't actually send anything in post and naturally you have nothing in $date variable. You need to set the data in the session after submitting the form, then read it from there.

Also as tips... your code have multiple problems:

1. Php js and html on same file -> this is usually a bad idea
2. Session start after output sent (added after reading comments - Bulk, did not notice it at first glance)
3. Multiple variables meaning the same think -> waste of memory
4. Footer after < /html>
5. Others (lack of comment, etc.)

Comment: i would like to make a separated timer.js file but how can I get the form value in the .js